# Python. Округление дробных намеренно вверх и вниз

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 0.001514
y = 0.002414
```

из этих чисел нужно получить x меньше, чем есть и y больше, чем есть.

```
x = 0.001 или x = 0.0015
y = 0.0025
```

числа могут быть различны, т.е. фиксированный round(x, 4) не подойдет, потому что могут быть 0.0001514 и тогда я получу x = 0.0002, что будет больше изначального числа.

Думал на счет fraction или побитовых операций, но как-то не совсем понимаю как это можно реализовать. Может быть кто-то делал подобное.

Comment: а так - `print(round(x, len(str(x).split('.')[1]))) `

Comment: Так все-таки каков алгоритм определения количества знаков после точки? Чтобы было два ненулевых символа или один?

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо, забыл, что можно преобразовывать в строки и работать со строками. Сделал с помощью строк, для меня работает, спасибо, но я избавился от дробных значений и преобразую во float только во время вывода в лог.

Comment: @suit Спасибо за замечание, т.к. на момент разработки не было особой разницы, я не акцентировал на этом внимание. Пусть будет два символа. Если у вас есть способ как это сделать с дробными числами, добавьте, пожалуйста, в ответ, я отмечу как ответ к вопросу, заранее благодарен.

Comment: опишите точно, что вы понимаете под *"округлением дробных намеренно вверх и вниз"*. Правила словами приведите и больше примеров, включая крайние случаи. Что в вопросе показано, не похоже на то как [режимы округления определены обычно](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_round)

Comment: @jfs например, числа: x = 0.001154 и y =  0.002454 нужно округлить до 0.0010 и 0.0025 соответственно. Под округлить я имею в виду оставить два не нулевых значения и взять число: для x меньше, чем 0.001154 (при round(x,4) получим 0.0012 > x); для y больше, чем 0.002454 (при round(y,4) получим 0.0024 < y).

Comment: @GermanGettsel не вижу каким образом 0.001 получили из 0.001154. Почему тогда 0.002454 не округлено до 0.002 или 0.003? Вы ссылку пытались читать какой из режимов округления вы пытаетесь использовать?

Comment: Это неправильное округление вверх, при таком округлении например 2,249 округлится до 2.3
при округлении до 1-го знака после запятой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number - число

precision - знаков в дробной части

Нужен:

```
import math
```

Вниз:

```
math.floor(number * 10 ** precision) / 10 ** precision
```

Вверх:

```
- math.floor(- number * 10 ** precision) / 10 ** precision
```